# How to use jQuery to load a module when completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When a page is finished loading. Then I want to load a module other, smaller, inside it using jQuery. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to wait for the every asset to finish loading, then do something like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $.getScript('/path/to/file.js');
});
```

You can also use an optional callback method:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $.getScript('/path/to/file.js', function(){
        //Called when script is loaded
    });
});
```

[jQuery docs for `$.getScript()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getScript#urlcallback)

*Just to be clear*, `$(window).load()` fires when everything on the page has finished loading including other scripts and images. `$(document).ready()` fires as soon as the DOM can be manipulated, which is often much sooner than `$(window).load()`.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use [$.getScript(url)](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getScript#urlcallback)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() { $.getScript(url) });
```

Comment: This is the `$(document).ready()` event function and is called when the DOM is ready to be manipulated, not when the page has finished loading per se.